# Django -Ajax Request Error : Not Found

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-views

I am trying to create an ajax function that when called returns info to newly created modal, can You help me out to find where the issue is?, I get the error "not found" whenever I try to access the URL in question, bellow I added a screenshot of my terminal and all the related files.

views.py

```
@require_POST()
def form_create(request, model):
  if request.method == "POST": 
    return HttpResponse("the model requested is")
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^forms/(?P<model>[\W-]+)/$','.views.form_create'),
```

Ajax call in html template

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/forms/"+model+"/",
     type: "POST",
     cache: false,
     success: 
         function(result){
             $("#myModalLabel").html(result);
             $("#companyModal").modal("show");  
             },
     error: 
         function(xhr){
             alert("Error: " + xhr.statusText);
             return false;
             }
     });
```

[image]

Comment: did you set your DEBUG=True?

Comment: Of course I set It to True

Comment: Because your accessing post, define the csrf in the ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "/forms/"+model+"/",
     type: "POST",
     cache: false,
     data: { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}' }, 
     success: 
         function(result){
             $("#myModalLabel").html(result);
             $("#companyModal").modal("show");  
             },
     error: 
         function(xhr){
             alert("Error: " + xhr.statusText);
             //alert(xhr.responseText) --> to get the full details of error
             return false;
             }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

`\W` (uppercase) matches any ***non***-alphanumeric character. You probably should use `\w` (lowercase) which matches any *alphanumeric* character.

urls.py

```
url(r'^forms/(?P<model>[\w-]+)/$','.views.form_create'),
```

Comment: Now I see a Internal server error after using the lowercase w

Comment: That probably means it has now matched the url and the problem is somewhere else. I am not sure of the `'.views.form_create'` notation, that could be the culprit, otherwise something in your view function. The answer to that is actually beyond the scope of your original question. You could ask a new one, providing details on the Internal server error received to make it easier to help!